# CSS Grid up to 4 columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to get some kind of "dynamic" columns depending on the number of items.

The container can have 1 to 4 items. I would like the number of columns to be 3 if there are between 1-3 items and 4 columns if there are 4 items.

This is what I have right now, it works fine if there are 1-3 items, but if there are 4 items then the last one goes to the next row. If I have `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);` that would work fine for when there are 4 items only.

Is it possible to achieve this with CSS?

Thanks.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container > div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using *explicit* columns, which you define using `grid-template-columns`, use *implicit* columns, which the grid creates automatically, as needed.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container > div {
  grid-row: 1; /* keeps all items on the first row */
  border: 1px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works :D
Awesome, thank you so much :)

Comment: you can also consider grid-auto-flow:column instead of grid-row:1

Comment: what's the advantage over grid-row:1 ?

Comment: @JVLobo there is no advantage. It's a different way to do the same

Comment: ah, you mean using grid-auto-flow on the parent container, right?
sounds good too :)
thanks!

Comment: @JVLobo yes the parent

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns:0.33333fr; /* 0.333 = 1/3 */  
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container > div {
  height: 100px;
  margin:5px;
  border: 1px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

[@MichaelBenjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66873500/11171286) answer is the simplest approach but if you want you can do that with javascript also. This has the potential of being more complex if needed.. Like this:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".container div");
if (divs.length < 4) document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--gridCol", 3);
```

```css
:root {
  --gridCol: 4;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--gridCol), 1fr);
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container > div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
I was looking for a CSS-only approach in this case though.

Comment: @JVLobo Yea I mentioned that ***@MichaelBenjamin answer is the simplest approach***, I just added for future references ✌